How to Connect a Flutter App to Windows Server 2019 for File and Folder Retrieval
I'm working on a Flutter project and need to connect it to a Windows Server 2019 machine to fetch files and folders. The server hosts various documents and directories that I need to access within my Flutter application.
What would be the best approach to establish this connection and retrieve files and folders from the Windows Server 2019 within my Flutter app? Are there any specific packages or APIs available in Flutter for interacting with Windows servers?
I'm particularly interested in understanding the steps involved in establishing the connection securely and efficiently, as well as any potential challenges or considerations I should keep in mind while implementing this functionality. Any code snippets, examples, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

You would need to implement SMB. You could write your own. There are several good open-source Java implementations you could copy - e.g. smbj. Bonus points if you then publish it to pub.dev. If you could start an SFTP server on the Windows server, there are already Dart SFTP implementations.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
